# Strange Razor behavior?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax

I have the following code in my partial view of a ASP.NET MVC project :

```
@if (Model.Url != null && Model.Url.Length > 0)
{ <a href="@Model.Url" target="_blank" title="Besök extern sida"><img src="~/Content/Theme/images/icons/link_13x13.jpg" alt="Extern länk" /></a>  }
else
{<img src="~/Content/Theme/images/icons/link_13x13_inactive.jpg" alt="Extern länk saknas" />}
```

This works great!

But then I got this :

```
@if(!Model.PersoanlTagStatus.HasValue)
{ <div class="postContainer"> }
else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Ignore)
{ <div class="postContainer postConIgnore"> }
else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Favorite)
{ <div class="postContainer postConFav"> }
```

And this is not working at all? It complains at the if that it is missing its `}`?

Why?

Comment: You're not closing your `<div>`'s so Razor can't tell when your jumping from code to html and back again

Comment: @Forty-Two: good call. i didn't even see that. makes me wonder if my answer should be deleted...

Comment: @DaveA I like your answer (and upvoted it).  Maybe the OP has a single closing div below, and is using the logic to choose it's class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@if(!Model.PersoanlTagStatus.HasValue)
{ 
   @: <div class="postContainer"> 
}
else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Ignore)
{ 

   @: <div class="postContainer postConIgnore"> 
}
else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Favorite)
{ 

   @: <div class="postContainer postConFav"> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@{
    if(!Model.PersoanlTagStatus.HasValue)
    {
    @<div class="postContainer"></div> 
    }
    else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Ignore)
    {
    @<div class="postContainer postConIgnore"></div>
    } 
    else if(Model.PersoanlTagStatus == ProjectX.Models.TagTypeKey.Favorite)
    {
    @<div class="postContainer postConFav"></div> 
    }
}
```